# Css background image with opacity 0.5

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I would like to have a background image, from a URL (So I can't edit its opacity manually)
with an low opacity and write content on top of it:
but the content should be with the normal 1 opacity

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/BAJN5/

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/BAJN5/1/ slightly better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `opacity` property is inherited. If you set `opacity` < 1 for an element, all its child elements will also have that < 1 value for `opacity` and *you cannot change this*.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use *multiple backgrounds* and have a semi-transparent background on top of your image. Of course, this raises some browser compatibility problems (see [multiple backgrounds support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) and [gradient support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)).

Example here: http://dabblet.com/gist/2818293 (should work in IE10, Opera 11+ and every non-dinosaur version of other desktop browsers)

There is also the option of not setting the background on the parent, but on a child with no children of its own (or on a pseudo-element), that is *absolutely positioned* and has a `z-index` < than that of the parent (which has an `rgba` background).

Comment: is it my browser or the picture is still with opacity 1 -----> indeed, doesn't work on Chrome but does on Firefox

Comment: see http://dabblet.com/gist/2819423, with opacity 0 you should not see the image, but on Chrome it does (Chrome under Ubuntu)

Comment: With `rgba(255,255,255,0)` you should see the image just as it is. The first background listed is the one that is applied on top. `rgba(255,255,255,0)` means completely transparent. So if the background on top is completely transparent, you should see the one below just as it is; as if there was no other background on top of it.

Comment: yes sry i decreased it instead of increase it, since it's the mask on top of the image

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BAJN5/2/

Try setting it this way:

```
<div style="position:relative"> <!-- wrapper div (relative) -->
    <div style="background:url(an-image-url) no-repeat center center; opacity:0.5; height:220px"></div> <!-- half opacity background -->
    <span style="opacity:1; position:absolute; z-index:1"><!-- full opacity (absolute) -->
        some text
        ......
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

see i have made through pseudo-elements :before & :after

**HTML**

```
<div class="addFav">
 <div>asdfasfasfafs</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.addFav:before {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports) no-repeat;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    color:#000;
    padding:15px;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    opacity:0.1;    
}


.addFav {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    color:red;
    padding:15px;
    position:relative
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/66/

Updated Demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/68/

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-background-image-hacks/) shows a technique for emulating background image opacity using a psuedo element

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should want this

Define your Main Div **rgba** properties

```
div {
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5);
}
```

more info http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: He has an image background, not a solid colour background.